# .htaccess add www AND ensure https://

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Been wrestling with this for quite a while with no success. What I'm looking for is an .htaccess rule to ensure all requests:

1. always start with "www"
2. are always secure (https)

Of all the rules I tried, perhaps this was the closest:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

This set of rules works great for:

- `http://www.example.com` > `https://www.example.com`
- `http://example.com` > `https://www.example.com`

Doesn't work for:

- `http://www.example.com/index.cfm?myquerystring`
- `http://example.com/index.cfm?myquerystring`

---

UPDATE:

The actual problem in my case is that for certain file extensions (.cfm,.cfml,.cfc) the request was being "handed off" to the application server before my rewrite rules were able to take affect. Thanks to all who responded.

Comment: Is this the only rule or you have more rules also?

Comment: this is the only rule

Comment: upon further inspection, while these were the only rules in the .htaccess file, the rule was being "overridden" by some settings in the main Apache configuration file. thank you for your insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you. Your rule works fine. It turns out my .htaccess file was not cooperating because it was conflicting with some settings in the main apache configuration file. Regardless, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Please, note that the .htaccess should be located in the website main folder.

Comment: That looks like it should take care of the secure (https) consideration, but what if I give it `https://mysite.com`. In this case, it should add the "www", but it will miss the condition in your rule.